# c++ reverse a linkedlist without changing the original one

Tags: c++

I'm trying to reverse a linkedlist, but I don't want to change the original linkedlist passed in by reference, how can I solve it?

```
typedef Node * ListType 

ListType reverse(ListType list) {
   if (list == NULL) {
      return list;
   }
   ListType curr = list;
   //printList(list);               //list unchanged 
   ListType prev=NULL, next=NULL;
   while (curr != NULL) {     
      next = curr->next;
      curr->next = prev;
      prev = curr;
      curr = next;  
   }
   //printList(list);              //list changed(I dont't want it changed)
   return prev;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing here that gets passed by reference, so what you are asking here is totally unclear.

Comment: Can you use a `std::list` and `std::list<type>::reverse_iterator`?

Comment: Do you know how to *copy* a list (without reversal)?

Comment: You're changing the value of the Next pointer.... so no you can't do this without affecting the original list.  You need to make new Nodes copy the value of the Nodes and return a reversed copy of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to change the original list, you have to make a *copy* of it. Iterate through the original list, prepending new nodes to the reversed list, then return it.

For example:

```
typedef Node* ListType;

ListType reverse(ListType list) {
    if (!list) {
        return NULL;
    }
    //printList(list); //list unchanged
    ListType curr = list, head = NULL, tail = NULL, copy;
    ListType *n = &tail;
    do {
        copy = new Node;
        copy->prev = NULL;
        copy->next = head;
        copy->data = curr->data; // copy your data field(s) as needed...
        *n = copy;
        n = &(copy->prev);
        head = copy;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    while (curr);
    //printList(list); //list still unchanged
    return head;
}
```

Just make sure the caller frees the returned list after using it.